# Angular2 @Input from async pipe - availability in ngOnInit

Tags: angular

On one blog I've read that:

> The ngOnInit lifecycle hook is a guarantee that your bindings are
>   readily available.

Is it true also with parameters passed using async pipe? For example:

```
<myComponent [myInput]="myObservableVariable | async">
 ...
</myComponent>
```

Will component wait for the variable to be resolved before starting up ngOnInit?

That would mean that sometimes, when data will take a while to resolve, component loading could take a long time.

Comment: Why not try it and find out? Add `.delay(10000)` on `myObservableVariable` and `console.log` in `ngOnInit` and see what happens when.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The short answer is no, the component instantiation won't be delayed and you will not get a resolved value in `onInit` **if the observable hasn't been resolved before the first change detection cycle.**

Compare the following:

```
  // the value will be available in onInit
  obs = Observable.from([33]);

  // the value will not be available in onInit (you'll get null)
  obs = new Observable(observer => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next(33);
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.complete();
    }, 3000);
  });


<child-component [inputproperty]="obs"><child-component>
```

Here is what happens under the hood when you use `async` pipe:

`async` pipe has a method `transform` which is called on every change detection cycle. this method is responsible for returning the current resolved value of the observable that will be passed down to a child component. If the observable hasn't been resolved before the first change detection cycle, your child component will get `null` in `onInit`.

Then, during next digest cycle your binding will be updated as `transform` will return resolved values. What's interesting is that resolution of an observable can trigger the change detection cycle. You can obtain new values for the bindings in `onChanges` lifecycle hook.

Comment: This is a really good insight on inner workings of async pipe. That explained a lot, thanks!

Comment: @charlie_pl, you're welcome, you might find [this article](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) on change detection interesting as well

Answer (score 9):

No, the bindings being *available* doesn't mean that their values have been *resolved* (and they may change later anyway). You can demonstrate this with a simple example:

```ts
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'sub-component',
  template: `<p>{{ myInput }}</p>`,
})
export class SubComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() myInput: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('initialised with', this.myInput);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    <sub-component [myInput]="content$ | async"></sub-component>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  name = 'Angular'; 
  content$ = Observable.of('Hello world').delay(5000);
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/jX7hOafuJtsWYhYrJx07?p=preview

In the console you will see `initialised with null`, then five seconds later the text will appear in the sub component.

If you want to know when the `@Input` data changes, you need to implement [`OnChanges`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-interface.html).

Answer (score 2):

i know the question was answered but also to give an official reference as its covered nicely in docs:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#when-to-set-form-model-values-ngonchanges

changedetection & lifecycle hooks happen independently (thus async) from Observable values resolution so you cannot have any guarantee whatsoever that you'll have data at the moment of onInit. 
Thats exactly what onChanges is for.