# Angular async pipe and http/delayed observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, angular-observable

Can somebody explain me, why in the following example the `@Input` is null if I access it in `ngOnInit` of OtherComponent (the http call was successful)?

*SomeComponent:*

```
@Component({   
selector: 'some-component',   
template: `<other-component [data]="observable$ | async"></other-component>`,   
styles: [``] }) 
export class SomeComponent  {

    observable$: Observable<any>;

    ngOnInit(): void {
      observable$ = this.http.get(...); // service call via angular httpClient 
    }
```

*OtherComponent:*

```
@Component({   
selector: 'other-component',   
template: `<div>...</div>`,   
styles: [``] }) 

export class OtherComponent  {

    @Input()
    data: any;

    ngOnInit(): void {
     // if I access this.data here, it is null
    }
```

According to the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) the async pipe subscribes to an observable and returns the latest value it has emitted. So I thought, the async pipe will pass down the result of the http call and not null.

If I use *ngIf, the result of the http call is passed down and not null.

```
<other-component *ngIf="observable$ | async as observable" [data]='observable'>
```

*Stackblitz example:*

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xghrjg

Comment: **asynchronous**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean

Comment: I found an answer to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044974/angular2-input-from-async-pipe-availability-in-ngoninit

Answer (score 1):

**Template:**

```
<other-component [data]='observable$ | async'>
```

**OtherComponent:**

```
@Component({   
selector: 'other-component',   
template: `<div>...</div>`,   
styles: [``] }) 

export class OtherComponent  {

    @Input()
    data: any;

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    ngOnChanges(){
      console.log(this.data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that at the time child component (in your case `OtherComponent`) was initialized the data was not there yet because data is loaded asynchronously.

Because of that Angular has `OnChanges` lifecycle hook which then gives you ability to manage data as it changes coming as Input().

Documentation -> https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

Updated Stackblitz -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkgcj9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdummy.component.ts

Important piece is

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
  this.transformedData = changes.data.currentValue; 
}
```

Comment: I know that it work with ngOnChanges, but I don‘t want to take care about any changes. The initial value of the observable contains all the data I need. I just don‘t understand why the value is null in ngOnInit. I thought the async pipe „resolves“ the values of the observable before ngOnInit is called.