# In Angular 9, how do I get a child component to reload after the parent has loaded data through an Observable?

Tags: angular, observable, parent-child, angular9

In my Angular 9 application, I want to pass some data from a parent component into a child component.  The parent loads that data via an observable.  Below is what the parent item looks like ...

```
<div>
    <h3 align="center">Hot Items</h3>
    <app-items [items]="items" ></app-items>
</div>
```

and then in the ts file, I have this

```
export class HotComponent implements OnInit {

  items: Item[] = [];

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiService.getHotItems().subscribe((result: ResultSet) => {
      this.items = result.hot_items;
    });
  }
```

But I notice when the observable loads the data, it is not getting displayed in the child component.  I think maybe I'm passing it to the child incorrectly?  Below is the ts file of the child component ...

```
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Item>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['title', 'notes'];
  @Input('items') items: Item[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.items);
  }
```

and the child component template has the below

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
    ...
```

How do I get the child component to reload when the parent component loads the data?

Comment: You’re really only setting the data once in ngOninit. Try to do this in ngOnChanges instead?

Comment: Regardless, leave the parents empty like this: `@Input() items: Item[] = [];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to replace

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.items);
}
```

with

```
ngOnChanges(changes): void {
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.items);
}
```

as @MikeOne suggests in his comment

Answer (score 0):

Here what you are doing in right but one thing is that, variable reference is not changing so the value in [**`@Input`**](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) variable in child component.

Try to implement with Observable, like below

In View:

```
  <app-items [items]="items$ | async" ></app-items>
```

In Template:

```
 ...

 ngOnInit() {
    this.items$ = this.apiService.getHotItems();
 }

 ...
```

Please refer to the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44045165/9764133) for more info.

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this answer.  Is there any advantage to doing this "| async" approach vs implementing the onChanges interface as suggested in comments?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand but the variable reference is actually changing in HotComponent this.items is set to a new array within the observable. The problem would probably still be that the dataSource are only set on init in the child component and any changes to items are ignored. Does this solution work?
@satish working with observables is great. I highly suggest learning how to use them.

Comment: @satish yes, with `async` we don't need to worry about the change of emitted value. It will update dynamically where as with ngOnChanges, value will be assigned multiple times to the datasource when ever any Input bound property change happens for that component.